# Change xtype combo to lovcombo EXT JS 2

Tags: javascript, extjs

I currently have a list with support products which shows me the names of the support products. What I want to do is that from that combo you can choose more than one value. I tried with lovcombo but it does not work for me.

I appreciate your help

```
        xtype : 'combo',
                fieldLabel: this.i18n.fieldProdApoyo,
                     hiddenName  : 'fovaFisioProdApoyo',
                     displayField: 'mateNombre',
                     valueField  : 'mateId',
                  typeAhead   : true,
                  emptyText: this.i18n.comboProductosEmptyText,
                  forceSelection: true,
                  titleCollapse: true,
                  triggerAction: 'all',                  
                  store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                           url : ctx + '/material.do',
                           autoLoad : true,
                           remoteSort : false,
                           baseParams : {
                                 op : 'listCombo'
                           },
                           sortInfo : {
                                 field : "mateNombre",
                                 direction : "ASC"
                           },
                           fields : ['mateId', 'mateNombre']                    
                     })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try multiSelect:true; in that combo. Remember that it will work with 'Ctrl' press when you select more than one value.

Comment: Can you provide a example fiddle for this?

Comment: What does fiddle mean? Example?